# jQuery - escaping inline styles with HTML entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across a curious problem when attempting to insert HTML edited by a Javascript editor (CKEditor) into some div. In the HTML to be inserted, double-quotes are replaced by the HTML entity &quot; which works fine.

EXCEPT if the &quot; appears in an inline style - then jQuery removes the entire inline sytyle.

I don't want them to be removed. I do prefer to keep the HTML entities if possible. The question is why does this happen? Any workaround?

In below example, I insert a text which should make the span red with regular quotes and with HTML-entity escaped quotes in an inline style.

The first line (div1) makes the span red, div2 is not red at all.

```
   window.onload = function() {
 $('#div1').html('<span style="color:red;">This text "here" is red</span>, while this is not.' );
 $('#div2').html('<span style=&quot;color:red;&quot;>This text &quot;here&quot; is red</span>, while this is not.' ); }
```

[See JSFiddle/L7cq2pfd here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7cq2pfd/)

Comment: div2 style is not valid `style=&quot;color:red;&quot;` how do you get this style ?

Comment: CKEditor automatically does this, it adds inline styles when you edit. This is intended to help avoiding problems with texts containing quotes, but in this case it created a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery inserts this as `style="&quot;color:red;&quot;"` - convert `&quot;` to `"` with `replace(/&quot;/g, '"')` before inserting as HTML :

```
$('#div2').html('<span style=&quot;color:red;&quot;>This text &quot;here&quot; is red</span>, while this is not.'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"') );
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/kb709s27/**

**Why**? The automatically rendering of a `&quot;` to `"` is a browser feature, not a javascript feature. jQuery seems to parse the inserted HTML and tries to correct malformed attributes. If you insert

```
$('#div2').html('<span style=color:red>');
```

then jQuery corrects this and inserts `<span style="color:red">`. In your case jQuery only see a malformed attribute and therefore tries to correct it, wrapping `&quot;color:red;&quot;` into quotes.

Comment: Thanks - this makes it clear and is what I needed. I was missing that the automatic HTML rendering is not a Javascript feature.